# C implementation of exponentiation by squaring

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, computation-theory

I tried to implement the "exponentiation by squareing" algorithmn in C but my program has an odd behaviour. First, here is a small code snippet:

```
long long fast_power_1(long long base, long long power){
    long long result = 1;
    while (power > 0)
    {
        if (power % 2 == 0)
        {
            power = power / 2;
            base = base * base;
        }
        else
        {
            power = power - 1;
            result = (result*base);
            power = power / 2;
            base = (base * base);
        }
    }
return result;}
```

If I call the function with:

```
printf("%d\n",fast_power_1(2,100));
```

I expect the output to be something like 976371285, but the result is 0 and i don't quite understand why.

Comment: Fyi, `%d` is not the proper format specifier for a `long long`. Consult your documentation.

Comment: well `2**100` doesn't fit in a long long if a long long is 64 bits which is likely.

Comment: `long long` is unlikely to have 100 bits.

Comment: Since you expected 976371285, you were probably supposed to do *modular* exponentiation modulo 1000000007.

Comment: `printf("%d\n",fast_power_1(2,100));` should have generated a compiler warning.  Enable all warnings and save time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`long long` should be printed using `%lld` format specifier otherwise it's Undefined Behavior. Also this method already has overflow within for large values of `power` - because long long cant hold `2^100`(as of now in `32` or `64` bit systems- when it is `128` bit system of course it can).

As of now in your code if you provide not too large value of the exponent and use `printf("%lld",..)` then it would give you a valid result.

Maybe you wanted to have modular arithmetic with it. (In general requirements stop at that - like modulo some large prime i.e, `10^9+7` ).

Comment: Yeah I totally forgot to tell, that i wanted to try modular arithmetic with it.