# The c code for power function is giving wrong result for particular value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int base, exponent;
    printf("Enter the value of base: ");
    scanf("%d", &base);

    printf("Enter the value of exponent: ");
    scanf("%d", &exponent);

    int power = pow(base, exponent);
    printf("%d", power);
    return 0;
}
```

The code when run gives correct value for all the input except when `base`=5 and `exponent`=4. The answer comes is 624 but it should be 625.

Comment: Change `power` to `double` to get a proper value (you can change `base` and `exponent` as well). See also here about floating point calculations issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892908/why-dont-operations-on-double-precision-values-give-expected-results

Comment: @selbie which is also a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c)

Comment: You could use integer calculations (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820057/c-implementation-of-exponentiation-by-squaring) or [round](https://godbolt.org/z/19rqcWdxq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a deficient implementation of `pow`. Although the correct result, 625, is representable, it is returning 624.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875.

`pow` is a difficult function to implement well, and some implementations do not return correct results even when the exact real-number-arithmetic result is representable in the `double` format. The function is implemented using approximations, and sometimes those approximations produce inaccurate results.

If you change the code to:

```
double power = pow(base, exponent);
printf("%g\n", power);
printf("%.99g\n", power);
```

you will see output like:

```
625
624.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875
```

The first line shows the result rounded to six significant decimal digits (the default for a `g` conversion) and then trimmed of trailing zeros. The second line shows the exact value. (Some C implementations may also fail to show the exact value in this line, but they should show you enough to distinguish it from 625.)

When 624.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875 is converted to `int`, the fraction part is discarded, leaving 624. This explains the output you observed.

Comment: THANKS for this brief explanation. I completely understood this now.